# How to create shadow only left and right side, on a line?

Tags: html, css

i have a line of width: 15px; and height of 2px; 
my question is, how to create the shadow only on right and left side?

Comment: I've always done that with images; I'd be interested to see if it's even possible with CSS.

Comment: required field validation message: [this is done with the css](http://blogtrottr.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (based on the [link you gave in your comment above](http://blogtrottr.com/)):

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

You can tweak it to how you like it using the [CSS3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/)

Comment: No problems :) glad I could help

Answer (score 5):

This fiddle has examples showing shadows only on:

- Top and bottom
- Left and right
- Top

With that you should be able to do any kind of shadow.

http://jsfiddle.net/rafaelchiti/5jdHW/

The code:

```
div {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;    
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.horizontal {
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset, 
              0px -15px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;  
}

.vertical {
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset, 
              0px -15px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;  
}

.one-side {
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

***CSS Box Shadow***
Add the following class to apply shadow. [Check this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/krhG7/)

```
.shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 10px 1px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 1px #000;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 10px 1px #000;
}
```

1. **The horizontal offset** of the shadow, positive means the shadow will
   be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on
   the left of the box.
2. **The vertical offset** of the shadow, a negative one means the
   box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means the shadow
   will be below the box.
3. **The blur radius (optional)**, if set to 0 the shadow will be sharp,
   the higher the number, the more blurred it will be.
4. **The spread radius (optional)**, positive values increase the size of
   the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the
   shadow is same size as blur).
5. **Color** Hexadecimal color value.

Comment: this link shows the shadow on right and bottom of div. i want only right and left shadow.

Comment: Hi, the box shadow support -ve values also. So you can adjust the values for making it to the left. But you cannot directly put the shadow on the left and right only. Instead of that try making two boxes and apply shadow for that. [Example for doing that](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/krhG7/16/)

Answer (score 1):

```
        .box {
            height: 150px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .top {
            box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -5px #333;
        }

        .right {
            box-shadow: -5px 0 5px -5px #333;
        }

        .bottom {
            box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
        }

        .left {
            box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #333;
        }

        .all {
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
        }
```

in the body put..

```
    <div class="box top"></div>
    <div class="box right"></div>
    <div class="box bottom"></div>
    <div class="box left"></div>
    <div class="box all"></div>
```